# How to acquire complete list of subdirs (including subdirs of subdirs)?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation, stata-macros

I have thousands of city folders (for example `city1`, `city2`, and so on, but in reality named like `NewYork`, `Boston`, etc.). Each folder further contains two subfolders: `land` and `house`.

So the directory structure is like:

```
current dictionary
  ---- city1
     ----- house 
         ------ many .xlsx files
     ----- land
  ----- city2
  ----- city3
  ···
  ----- city1000
```

I want to get the complete list of all subdirs and do some manipulation (like `import excel`). I know there is a macro extended function: `local list: dir` to handle this issue, but it seems it can only return the `first tier` of subdirs, like `city_i`, rather than those deeper ones.

More specifically, if I want to take action within all house folders, what kind of workflow do I need?

I have made an initial attempt to write code to achieve my goal:

```
cd G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data
local folder: dir . dirs "*"
foreach i of local folder {
     local `i'_house : dir  "G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data\``i''\house" files "*.xlsx"

     local count = 1
     foreach j of local `i'_house {
        cap import excel "`j'",clear
        cap sxpose,clear
        cap drop in 1/1

        if `count'==1 {
          save `i'.dta, replace
            }
        else          {
         cap qui append using `i'
         save `i'.dta,replace
            }

       local ++count
     }
}
```

There is something wrong with:

```
``i''
```

in the dir, I struggled to make it work without success, anyway.

I have [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872508/how-to-tokenize-a-extended-macro-local-dir-in-stata/34875242?noredirect=1#comment57574055_34875242) on this project.

---

**Supplementary remarks:**

As Nick points out, it's the back slash that causes the trouble. Moving from that point, however, I encounter another problem. Say, without the complicated actions, I just want to test if my loops work, so I write the following code snippet:

```
set more off
cd G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data
local folder: dir . dirs "*"
foreach i of local folder {
     di "`i'"
     local `i'_house : dir  "G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/`i'\house" files "*.xlsx"

     foreach j of local `i'_house {
        di "`j'"
     }
}
```

However, the outcome on the screen is something like:

```
city1
project100
project99
······
project1
```

It seems the code only loops one round, over the first city, but fails to come to `city2`, `city3` and so on. I suspect it's due to my problematic writing of the local, especially in this line but I'm not sure:

```
foreach j of local `i'_house
```

Comment: Backslashes do not mix with local macros. Much documented e.g. http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u.pdf 18.3.11 http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0042

Comment: @NickCox, thanks nick, it's indeed the back slash cause the problem. Moving from this point, I encounter a new problem, please give me some new inspiration.

Comment: If the items in `folder` have embedded spaces, they aren't suitable to be macro names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not a solution to whatever problem you're actually presenting, an easier way might be to use `filelist`, from SSC (`ssc install filelist`).

An example might be:

```
. // list all files
. filelist, directory("D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example")
Number of files found = 5

. 
. // strange way of tagging directories ending in "\house"
. // change at will
. gen tag = substr(reverse(dirname),1,6) == "esuoh/"

. 
. order tag

. list

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | tag   dirname                                                     filename             fsize |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   0   D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example/proj_1                     newfile.txt              0 |
  2. |   1   D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example/proj_2/house               somefile.txt             0 |
  3. |   0   D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example/proj_3/subproj_3_2         newfile2.txt             0 |
  4. |   1   D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example/proj_3/subproj_3_2/house   anothernewfile.txt       0 |
  5. |   1   D:\Datos\RFERRER\Desktop\example/proj_3/subproj_3_2/house   someotherfile.txt        0 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Afterwards, use `keep` or `drop`, conditional on variable `tag`.

Graphically, the directory looks like:

[image]

(I'm on Stata 13. Check `help string functions` for other ways to tag.)

Comment: thanks, it's glad to hear such a useful command exist. However, it's not quite suitable for my particular purpose, for I want to extract files from **certain** subfolders, not all. In `filelist` , as far as I can see from the help file, one can only choose the pattern of file's, not dir's

Comment: `filelist` creates a dataset with information on what was found. To proceed, you only need to discard what you define as irrelevant.

Comment: thank you Roberto, after some struggle, the (truly smart) approach works. However, I wonder when I have hundreds of thousands of files (more even more), can `valuesof` store such large amount of values? I use stata14

Comment: See `help limits`, for **# of characters in a macro** and the possibilities to expand. Without knowing beforehand the approximate number of characters I need to store, I'd try to avoid using a _macro_.

Answer (score 0):

Your revised problem may yield to

```
local folder: dir . dirs "*"
foreach i of local folder {
     di "`i'"
     local house : dir  "G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/`i'\house" files "*.xlsx"

     foreach j of local house {
        di "`j'"
     }
}
```

but clearly we can't see your file structure or file names.